# Issue while displaying correctly an error message for Invalid credentials

Tags: swift, rawstring

I would like to display the content of the error received from my server in my iPad apps using Swift, but I can not display it correctly:

```
(lldb) po (response.rawString)
"{\"message\":\"Invalid Credentials\"}"
```

I would like to display only :
Invalid Credentials

Answer (score 1):

You could add a custom type for your error and make it conform to `Codable`

```swift
struct ServerError: Error, Codable {
    let message: String
}
```

and then decode value of `response.rawString` using `JSONDecoder`

```swift
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
guard
    let data = response.rawString.data(using: .utf8),
    let error = try? decoder.decode(ServerError.self, from: data)
else {
    return
}
print(error.message) // output: Invalid Credentials
```